# Methods to dissect or parse long, difficult sentences

Tags: english, parsing, french

**TL;DR:** Only English and French can I manage and so ask for. Instead of repeating 'long, difficult' hereafter, denote it *mazy*. [Mazy sentences still stifle my reading comprehension](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/42834/8712); so I was gladdened to witness the array of techniques [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/235034/50720) to parse these mazy sentences.

1. What are these techniques called exactly?

2. Are there books or resources on such strategies?

3. What are some other techniques, NOT already discussed below?

*[All below this parenthesis is optional reading. Each grey line denotes a separate ELU question.]*

1.1. https://english.stackexchange.com/a/235034/50720 injects new words to help clarify and complete the mazy sentence.

1.2. https://english.stackexchange.com/a/235055/50720 both injects new words and punctuations.

1.3. https://english.stackexchange.com/a/235174/50720 fragments the sentence and then indents each relative clause. Is this based on [multiple center embedding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_embedding) as mooted [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/235082/50720)?

---

2.1. https://english.stackexchange.com/a/152936/50720 simply parenthesises the existing sentence.

2.2. https://english.stackexchange.com/a/153107/50720 parenthesises more intensively than .

---

3. https://english.stackexchange.com/a/217866/50720 labels each word with its category.

Comment: These are not methods of parsing sentences but of depicting the parses.

Comment: @StoneyB I think this is just a different meaning of parse. These are methods for enabling readers to mentally parse sentences that they would be able to otherwise, no?

Comment: @Araucaria W e l l ... I suppose you could argue that each kind of depiction is accompanied by more or less explicit rules for which piece goes where on the diagram; Reed-Kellogg or the four-piece minimalist trees for instance. But it seems to me that it is the rules which constitute the parsing 'method', not the pictorial form which results.